# Can prone always be used as a synonym of sensitive?

Tags: synonyms

Can prone always be used as a synonym of sensitive? For example, is the sentence "Rabits are prone to humid conditions." equivalent to "Rabits are sensitive to humid conditions."? The first sentence seems to use "prone" incorrectly, but I'm not a native speaker, so I can't tell for sure.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is being asked. OP seems to already suspect that *prone* doesn't mean the same as *sensitive*, and the definitions of both words can easily be found in dictionaries. It just looks like General Reference to me.

Comment: Being prone to criticism means tending to get a lot of it. Being sensitive to criticism means tending to make a lot of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is right. To be "prone" is not to be sensitive, but to have a tendency toward something. Which isn't to say that we cannot connect rabbits with humidity using "prone"; it's just that it's not possible to have tendency toward humidity. But let's say that we agree that rabbits can have a tendency to, say, *suffer* in humid conditions. Then we can say, rabbits are prone to suffering in humid conditions. Aha, now that sounds fine.

It seems that the tendency expressed by prone is invariably toward something negative, as in "accident prone". For instance, prone is not used in a sense like "bookworms are prone to getting good grades in school".

Children can be prone to misbehaving; prisoners can be prone to fighting, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

No. Being *prone to* something means having *a tendency to* or being *liable to* do that.

> **prone** *adjective*
>   **1** (**prone to/to do something**) likely or liable to suffer from, do, or experience something unpleasant or regrettable:
>   *farmed fish are prone to disease*
>   [in combination]:
>   *he was written off by many as too injury-prone*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prone)

Rabbits cannot normally be “prone to humid conditions”: they have to be prone **to do something**. Rabbits might be **prone to overheating** in humid conditions, for example.

One might say that “rabbits are prone to humid conditions” if they live in the tropics. This is similar to ODO’s first example, where the subject may experience something unpleasant, and by living in the tropics they are likely to experience humidity. But in that case, it wouldn’t just be rabbits, and it doesn’t necessarily indicate that they are sensitive to those conditions.

Comment: Both replies are very helpful! I wish I could accept both.

Comment: @ToonVerstraelen I saw your vacillation :)